# How to add both image and title while answering to an inline query?

Tags: python, message, media, telethon

I am using the telethon library for my telegram bot, and I am struggling with how to add both image and title in an inline query handler.

Right now I am using the following code:

`await event.answer([builder.photo(path_to_local_jpeg_file, text='text', include_media=False)])`

It works fine with my jpeg file, but when I make the inline query it is marked as "Untitled". An attribute `title`, which would seem logical, is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution. The jpeg file has to stored externally.

```
    photo = types.InputWebDocument(
            url=url,
            size=0,
            mime_type="image/jpeg",
            attributes=[],
        )
    title = "title"
    await event.answer([
        builder.article(title, text=title, thumb=photo, content=photo)
    ])
```